# Find/replace on block device?

Tags: block-device, replace, binary

Let's say I have an *unmounted* block device `/dev/sda`, and I want to replace all instances of `MyPassWord` with `XXXXXXXXXX`.  (Hopefully my goal is obvious.)

What's the easiest way to do this?

Comment: If you are going to replace on the block level I would make sure that the patterns are of equal length (now it is 10 resp. 12 characters). Whatever technique you are going to use.

Comment: How big is the block device?  "Easiest" could be to copy it to a file on another block device and then use 'sed'.  But it would be very slow.  Most efficient way would be to write a quick C program, but writing C isn't everyone's idea of easy.

Comment: Also keep in mind that if your password is split between two blocks of a file, those blocks might not be adjacent on the disk.  So you might not find all occurrences.

Comment: @Anthon: Oops, yes I meant to assume that, I counted my X's wrong.

Comment: @dataless: That's a good idea...I'd really prefer to be able to do the replacement in-place, though.

Comment: @dataless: And yes, I realize the data might not be adjacent.  Let's assume that I know that it is.

Comment: well i could write said C program, but I hesitate to post it on SE without some thorough testing which I don't have time for atm.  And maybe someone else will post a ready-made utility for the problem?  Oh, and you might be able to edit block devices with some hex editor.

Comment: @dataless: I'm sort of surprised this sort of thing doesn't already exist in the UNIX world...sure it may not always be a good idea, but still...

Comment: There is `bbe`, which would be a better fit than the line oriented `sed`, but unfortunately it doesn't have a mode for in-place substitution.

Comment: @dataless that is easily remedied by reading the length of the pattern more than a block (and writing it on change), but stepping with block size. See my answer.

Comment: @Anthon I think you misunderstood me; the filesystem is not guaranteed to put two adjacent file chunks on adjacent device blocks.  So its possible to have a file still containing the password even if the complete string doesn't exist anywhere on the block device.

Comment: @dataless Yes I misunderstood, that is indeed not guaranteed and I had not thought about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

device = '/dev/sdi'
old_pattern = "MyPassWord"
new_pattern = "XXXXXXXXXX"

assert len (old_pattern) == len(new_pattern)

BS = 1024 ** 2  # 1 Mb buffer
# read a few bytes more to account for occurences of the pattern on the edge
READSIZE = BS + len(old_pattern)

offset = 0
with open(device, 'r+b') as fp:
    assert isinstance(fp, file)
    while True:
        try:
            fp.seek(offset)
        except IOError:
            #print 'offset', offset
            #raise
            break
        buf = fp.read(READSIZE)
        occurences = buf.count(old_pattern)
        if occurences:
            print offset, occurences
            fp.seek(offset)
            fp.write(buf.replace(old_pattern, new_pattern))
            fp.flush()
        offset += BS
```

substituting the appropriate device name at the top.

You have to run the script as `root` and make sure you re-mount the device when finished as the system buffers of file contents are not notified of the changes.

Comment: Hmm...I think this will fail to find `MyPassWord` if it falls any 1Mb boundary. +1 though

Comment: @notfed No it won't. I read (and write if applicable) READSIZE which is len(old_pattern) longer than BS, but I step by BS. The next read reloads a few bytes of the previous process

Comment: @notfed There is still the problem, as dataless correctly pointed out (and for which I needed extra clarification) that if `MyPassWord` is in a file and the blocks that hold the date of that file are not next to each other in the file, then this won't work. In that case you would need to scan each and every file through the filesystem, and do the same for deleted file that might be recovered (e.g. with `extundelete`)